# Why is it throwing errors while trying to email a multipart HTML message using Email::Send module?

Tags: perl

I have been trying to email a multipart HTML message but getting too many errors and warnings. I am using [`Email::Sender`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender) module for the `sendmail()` and [`Email::MIME`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME) to create the message.

Here's the relevant part of the code for reference. Really appreciate if anyone can point me to the mistake I am making and any pointer to eliminate it.

Note: All RHS variables are correctly assigned from a properties file. I had also printed them to check that they indeed are assigned the correct values.

```
use Email::MIME;
use Email::MIME::CreateHTML;
use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP qw();

my $smtpServer          = $mailSMTPHost;
my $smtpPort            = $mailSMTPPort;
my $smtpUser            = $mailLogin;
my $smtpPassword        = $mailPwd;

my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new({
  host => $smtpServer,
  port => $smtpPort,
  sasl_username => $smtpUser,
  sasl_password => $smtpPassword,
});

# for Email with HTML content
my $mailBody = $mailGreeting . $mailMsg . $mailSignature;
my $email = Email::MIME->create_html(
    header => [
      From    => $mailFrom,
      To      => $mailTo,
      Cc      => $mailCC,
      Bcc     => $mailBCC,
      Reply   => $mailReplyTo,
      Subject => $mailSubject
    ],
    body => $mailBody
);

eval { sendmail($email, { transport => $transport }); };
if ($@) {
# $@ is an object of Email::Sender::Failure
  print $@->message;
  print"\n".$@->code;
# print "Oh no!". $@->what;
} else{ print "sendmail success"; };
```

When running the code I am getting the following error:

```
Parsing of undecoded UTF-8 will give garbage when decoding entities at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/HTML/PullParser.pm line 81.
failed AUTH: Command unknown: 'AUTH'
500
```

Comment: Do you have MIME::Base64 and Authen::SASL installed? Looks like Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP needs them to authenticate. Add them to your list of modules to `use`.

Comment: @allen yes I have those two module installed and added to the use based on your advice. But the results are still the same unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I figured the issue was TLS. when I changed to use the module and accordingly updated the code, the email is being sent correctly; even though the Parsing warning is still thrown - do not know how to address that yet. Here are my changes:

```
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS;
my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS->new({
   host => $smtpServer,
   port => $smtpPort,
   username => $smtpUser,
   password => $smtpPassword,
 });
```